# What is the best way to highlight alternative rows when you have nested tables?

Tags: jquery, css-tables

I have a table and I highlight the alternative rows using this line:

```
$("table.altRow tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DEDFDE");
```

which works great except now, in one of the columns I have a separate nested table so I am seeing issues in the parent table around alternative rows.

So lets say I have 3 rows in the outer table:

Row 1
Row 2
Row 3

If there isn't a nested table I get:

Row 1: Dark
Row 2: Light
Row 3: Dark

but if I have a nested table in Row 1 with two rows, I get

Row 1: Dark  (Nested table row 1: dark, Nested Table row 2: light)
Row 2: dark
Row 3: Light

Is there anyway to have nested table not affect the alternate rows of the parent table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use child selectors `>` (make sure you add `tbody`):

```
$("table.altRow > tbody > tr:odd").css("background-color", "#DEDFDE");
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/LzZKD/1/)

Comment: This seems to give the same results . .

Comment: This fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/LzZKD/2/) is what would be the "same results", however the one in my answer does have alternating colors on parents only.

Comment: my point is that I DONT want the nested table to have alternative colors . . i just want the parent rows to always alternate no matter what the nested tables are doing . .

Comment: That is **exactly** what the Fiddle in my answer does... This Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/doitlikejustin/LzZKD/1/)

Comment: hmm . . i am trying to figure out why this isn't working on my table . . more debugging to do . . (i agree what you have in your fiddle is what i want.. . just trying to figure out why i can't reproduce given your suggestion :) )

Comment: Lol. Well at least you saw it is working, I thought I might be going crazy. You may want to try explicitly writing out `tbody` as well so the browser doesn't have to interpret it.

Comment: If the answer did work for you, I hope you will remove the downvote :)

Comment: so i wound up having to add an additional line to get it to work . . $("table.altRow > tbody > tr:even").css("background-color", "#EEECEE"); which means some other defaulting may have been happening

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use the `tablesorter` widget for jQuery, you can set **zebra** as a default widget option and never have to worry about this again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use nth-child
such as:

> table.altRow tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
>
> table.altRow tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}

you can also do nth-child(#) {style}

hope this helps